# How are people testing prototypes on Apple/Android watches?

Tags: apple, prototype

I usually use proto.io to mockup and then test prototypes right from the device. However, proto has yet to include this functionality for smart watches. (I can only test in browser). Does anyone here have any ideas on how to test right from the device (without creating the actual app)?

Comment: From my knowledge, it looks to be too early for fully-fledged testing prototypes for smartwatches.

Answer (score 4):

Paper prototyping is a quick and dirty way to do early usability testing. You can do that on a watch UI in the same way you do it for desktop/mobile UIs. Just print out your prototype screens and perform a usability test, swapping out the printouts as if they were live screens.

[Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccSooSLKrpE) (skip to 3:00).

See also: [Paper Prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_prototyping) and [Usability Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability_testing).

Comment: I've used this technique for evaluating desktop apps and it works surprisingly well. Good luck.